# Symfony: How to make JMS Serializer works with strict types?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, visitor-pattern

This is my situation:

I'm trying to write a Symfony REST API that works with "strict" types (integer, boolean and float), because default Symfony behaviour doesn't support it and I want to avoid force cast types (e.g: [JMS Serializer converts string value into integer field type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502472/how-to-make-jms-serializer-throw-an-exception-on-deserializing-json-instead-of-c))

To do this, I have created a custom handler which implements the `JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface`
(e.g a `StrictIntegerHandler`):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer;

use JMS\Serializer\Context;
use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;
use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\JsonDeserializationVisitor;
use JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

class StrictIntegerHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_DESERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'strict_integer',
                'method' => 'deserializeStrictIntegerFromJSON',
            ],
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'strict_integer',
                'method' => 'serializeStrictIntegerToJSON',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function deserializeStrictIntegerFromJSON(
        JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function serializeStrictIntegerToJSON(
        JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type, Context $context)
    {
        return $visitor->visitInteger($data, $type, $context);
    }
}
```

My entity looks:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Validator;

/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="persons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int age
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="integer")
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("strict_integer")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"Person"})
     *
     * @Validator\Type(type="integer", message="Age field has wrong type")
     */
    private $age;

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge(int $age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

When I throw the following POST actions, the JMS Serializer returns the correct results:

1. `{ "age" : 12 }` will result in `int(12)`
2. `{ "age" : "asdf" }` will result in `"Age field has wrong type"`

In both cases my method `deserializeStrictIntegerFromJSON` is called, so deserialize process works perfectly as I want.

Problems comes with serialize process: 
When I launch GET action (`/person/id_person`) I get the following exception:

> Expected object but got integer. Do you have the wrong @Type mapping
>   or could this be a Doctrine many-to-many relation?
>   (JMS\Serializer\Exception\LogicException)

Debug stack trace shows me that method `serializeStrictIntegerToJSON` is never called..

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution: I had to upgrade `jms/serializer` library to version 1.5.0.

My problem was that I was using `jms/serializer` (v1.1.0) whose `SerializationContext` class was throwing the previous `LogicException` in `isVisiting()` method because `strict_integer` type is not recognized in switch-case sentence from `accept()` method of `GraphNavigator` class.